# SQL query to replace commas by pipe symbol

Tags: sql, string

How to write an SQL query to replace commas by pipe symbol in a string, for example: `abc, def`.

Comment: Are you wanting to also remove the spaces as well?  Also, what happens if there is an actual text comma that shouldn't be replaced?

Answer (score 3):

use following query

```
update DATABASE_NAME.TABLE_NAME
  set FIELD_NAME = replace(
    FIELD_NAME,
    ‘find this string’,
    ‘replace found string with this string’
    );
```

also u can use for select only

```
SELECT REPLACE(‘www.mysql.com’, ‘w’, ‘Ww’);
```

Comment: and if I want to replace , with '?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command in the SQL standard, but most vendors implement this function as "replace():

- SQL Server: replace()
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx
- Oracle: replace()
  http://www.oradev.com/oracle_string_functions.jsp
- DB2: replace ()
  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_scalarfunctionsintro.htm
- mySQL: replace ()
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Here are some SQL Server examples:

- http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement

`SELECT Replace('SQLTeam.com Rocks!', 'Rocks', 'is cool') -- returns literal`

`Update dbo.authors
    Set    city = replace(city, 'Salt', 'Olympic'); -- Updates table`

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @str varchar(100)='abc,def'
SELECT REPLACE(@str,',','|')
```

Comment: Its sql specific,but you can use the same replace function in the same way in Oracle.

Comment: what if i want to replace it by '

Comment: Declare @str varchar(100)='abc''def'
SELECT REPLACE(@str,'''','|')

Comment: The Declare @str is Oracle specific and very non-standard sql.